# MediaWiki: Transclude pagename in template

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm creating a dictionary-type MediaWiki, where each article is a dictionary entry, with the word as the pagename, and to show the pronunciation I want to be able to use a template like `{{pronunciation|{{PAGENAME}}}}`, to include the pronunciation data on each entry. This way I can put all the pronunciation data onto one template instead of having to add it to each article manually.

At the moment I'm using an `if#` for the `{{pronunciation}}` template:

```
{{#if:{{{PAGENAME}}}
| word1 = pronunciation1
| word2 = pronunciation1
| word3 = pronunciation1
| #default =<!--blank-->
}}
```

But I'm not that clued up about #if templates and it isn't working. Can anyone tell me what to do to get it working? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the switch statement:

```
{{#switch:{{PAGENAME}}
| word1 = pronunciation1
| word2 = pronunciation1
| word3 = pronunciation1
| #default =<!--blank-->
}}
```

Also, so called magic words, such as `{{PAGENAME}}`, uses two curly braces, not three.

Note that you need to enable the [ParserFunctions extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) in LocalSettings.php, if you haven't already:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/ParserFunctions/ParserFunctions.php";
```